# Background image for menu item

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, background-image, menuitem

I am working on this site [edsys.in](http://www.edsys.in/). The last menu item anchor (**educational content**) has a background gif with text **trending new**. The image disappears when I apply the following CSS:

```
  background-position-y: 20px;
```

Setting a height on the anchor does not work.

This is my current CSS:

```
.trending a {
  background: url('http://www.edsys.in/wp-content/uploads/trending.gif') no-repeat bottom;
  background-position-x: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your background is being cut off because it overflows the anchor element. Simply adjusting the height will not work since the anchor is an inline element. Try setting your anchor to `display: block;` first, for example:

```
.trending a {
  background: url('http://www.edsys.in/wp-content/uploads/trending.gif') no-repeat bottom;
  background-position-x: 5px;
  background-position-y: 20px;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.trending a {
background: url('http://www.edsys.in/wp-content/uploads/trending.gif')no-repeat 5px bottom;
height:'';
width:'';
}
```

Comment: under educational content menu item

Comment: image for that menu item

Comment: So you can also use pseudo selctors :after and you can manipulate your background image